# Get avg, std deviation, min,max and count statistics in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, statistics

I have this code above in flask( using pymongo) server and i'm trying to get the statistics avg, std deviation, min ,max and count on files with 14 columns, Time, Yaw, Pitch, Roll, Heading, Ax, AY,AZ, Mx, My, Mz but i'm getting this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField
```

```
docs=db.datatest.aggregate([{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "null",
            "Time": {"$push": "$Time"},
            "Yaw": {"$push": "$Yaw"},
            "Pitch": {"$push": "$Pitch"},
            "Roll": {"$push": "$Roll"},
            "Heading": {"$push": "$Heading"},
            "Ax": {"$push": "$Ax"},
            "Ay": {"$push": "$Ay"},
            "Az": {"$push": "$Az"},
            "Gx": {"$push": "$Gx"},
            "Gy": {"$push": "$Gy"},
            "Gz": {"$push": "$Gz"},
            "Mx": {"$push": "$Mx"},
            "My": {"$push": "$My"},
            "Mz": {"$push": "$Mz"}
        }
    },
    {"$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Time": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Time", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Time"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Time"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Time"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Time"}
            },
            "Yaw": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Yaw", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Yaw"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Yaw"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Yaw"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Yaw"}
            },
            "Pitch": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Pitch", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Pitch"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Pitch"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Pitch"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Pitch"}
            },
            "Roll": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Roll", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Roll"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Roll"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Roll"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Roll"},
                "Heading": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Heading", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Heading"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Heading"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Heading"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Heading"}
            },
            "Ax": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Ax", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Ax"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Ax"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Ax"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Ax"}
            },
            "Ay": {"$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Ay", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Ay"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Ay"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Ay"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Ay"}
            },
            "Az": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Az", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Az"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Az"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Az"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Az"}
            },
            "Gx": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Gx", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Gx"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Gx"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Gx"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Gx"}
            },
            "Gy": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Gy", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Gy"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Gy"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Gy"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Gy"}
            },
            "Gz": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Gz", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Gz"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Gz"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Gz"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Gz"}
            },
            "Mx": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Mx", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Mx"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Mx"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Mx"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Mx"}
            },
            "My": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$My", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$My"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$My"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$My"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$My"}
            },
            "Mz": {
                "$avg": {"$reduce": {"input": "$Mz", "initialValue": [], "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
                "StdDev": {"$stdDevPop": "$Mz"},
                "Min": {"$min": "$Mz"},
                "Max": {"$max": "$Mz"},
                "Count": {"$size": "$Mz"}}
                }}}])
for documents in docs:
        return str(documents)
```

i've tried this code above but i'm getting a error

Comment: You need to give a name to the subfield that you are using for the averages for each field. You are doing it for the others but you don't have the same wrapper around `$avg`

Comment: thanks. it worked. I'm getting this error now, Exceeded memory limit for $group. Already tried the alowdiskuse for true but i have mongodb atlas free.